# IE11 becoming unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-11

I have a requirement where I need to play cine (a movie) out of a certain set of images. I am using HTML5 canvas to do that. I need to play four cine concurrently, but my browser IE11 quickly becomes unresponsive or relaunches itself. When it relaunches itself, I see in task manager that memory has reached to about 1.5 GB but when it becomes unresponsive there is no memory spike.
I have created a fiddle to demonstrate that. The same thing works fine in Chrome. 
The images are JPeg images (converted from Dicom) and I need to decompress them, put them onto a tempcanvas and read the pixel data for some manipulation before putting them back on to a canvas.

Can you help what could be the reason causing it, so I can change my design if required.

https://jsfiddle.net/hkuntal/03tjvhhn/

```
this.loadLossyData = function() {
        var lossyImage = new Image();
        lossyImage.onload = function() {
            input.tempCanvas.height = headerInfo.Rows;
            input.tempCanvas.width = headerInfo.Columns;
            var tempContext = input.tempCanvas.getContext("2d")
            tempContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0, headerInfo.Columns, headerInfo.Rows);
            var tempCanvasPixelData = tempContext.getImageData(0, 0, headerInfo.Columns, headerInfo.Rows);
            // SOME PIXEL MANIPULATION WILL BE DONE HERE ON tempCanvasPixelData
            drawImageOnCanvas(input.tempCanvas, input.canvas, input);
            this.onload = null;
            this.src = "";
        };
        lossyImage.src = jpegImageData;
```

Machine specs: 8 core, 18 GB RAM, NVidia graphics card, IE11, Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Looking through nothing seemed to stand out until I saw `setInterval`. It is the cause of your problem. Any delay and you will start queuing calls, and you end up presenting more work than the GC and the browser can manage . For animations use `requestAnimationFrame`, for all other timing stuff use `setTimeout`. If you use `setTimeout` don't set a new timeout until you have finished processing the current task. NEVER use `setInterval`

Comment: ok let me try with setTimeout, but if I understand correctly, setInterval does not queue up the callbacks unless the callback on the last interval is finished.

Comment: That is incorrect. `setInverval` pushes on the the call stack asynchronously. It is a nasty bit of work and is from my experience helping people fix page crashing issues the single biggest cause of browser crashes and  page crashes. It is not that the method is flawed, it is the way it is used that is at fault. It should never be used for tasks that are longer than the longest expected code execution time. As Javascript has indeterminate execution time the use of setInterval is always a potencial source of bad behaviour.

Comment: @Harryom, super late to the party, but if you're still having trouble, please let me know. I work on the [CornerstoneJS](https://cornerstonejs.org/) and could help you get a simple web based CineLoop player up quickly.